# Dual boot with multiple drives

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I just built a new PC, and I'm looking to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu. I have a 256gb SSD, which I would rather be dedicated to Windows. I also have a 2tb hard drive, which is where I'd like to put Ubuntu. I'd like Ubuntu to take about 256gb on the HDD, with about 1.75tb of shared storage for both Ubuntu and Windows. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Read the Ubuntu install guide and make sure you understand linux partitions. Ask if you get stuck.

Comment: As 256GB is fairly large, it would consider making 25 or 30 GB for / (root) on SSD and /home or a larger ext4 data partitions on HDD. Then some data unique to Linux can be in ext4 and data your want to share in NTFS partition(s) on HDD. What brand/model system/motherboard? Some require extra UEFI settings. Be sure to install both systems in UEFI boot mode. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: … combined with https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 0):

i did this before in my desk computer .
follow this steps :

1. install windows on the SSD .
2. install ubuntu partitions on the specified amount of the HDD drive.
3. format the left amount with NTFS or FAT32 file system .
4. finish the installations

**note :**
you can format the shared partition while installing ubuntu or after .

your partitions should look something like this :

- SSD (windows) :

  - C:\
  - D:\
- HDD (ubuntu) :

  - sda1 - Ubuntu (EXT4)
  - sda2 - Swap
  - sda3 - Shared partition between Ubuntu and Windows (NTFS or FAT32 Format)