# Multiple Hard Drives, Dual Boot (RST Error)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows, rst

My problem is similar to the one posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991137/dual-boot-with-multiple-drives), and I wish to achieve the same configuration. But I'm facing an Intel RST error when trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.

RST Error image during setup:

[image: RST Error]

As per my understanding after reading [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/), this mostly pertains to the SSD that Windows 10 is currently installed on, and that changing RST to AHCI might fatally damage my Windows installation entirely.

Can I ignore the RST bit if I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my second HDD (2TB)? This HDD on Windows is currently partitioned into two 1TB NTFS partitions, and I've unallocated 150GB from one of them for Ubuntu purposes.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please edit the question and include the exact error verbatim. This makes it much easier for us to Google your problem to quickly come up with an effective solution.

Comment: Install Windows AHCI drivers. You then may not have Windows fast start up having its own hibernation file, but hibernation/fast start up needs to be off anyway to dual boot. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/